# Connecting to Umbraco 6.2 from web application

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I need to iterate through the nodes in Umbraco 6.2 in the external web application.

But dont know how to make a connection in the code behind to Umbrao cms.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use umbraco web api.

Umbraco Web api would allow you to set up a restful web service that would call via a url with querystring parameters if required.

In the web api controller, you would have access to all of the Umbraco nodes and you could return results in xml or json format as required.

This is a good reference - https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/WebApi/

Wing